# Invocación al evento Click no funciona JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo una sucesión de divs dentro de otros divs que simulan unas ventanas dentro de otras, una de estas ventanas invoca a otra y cada una tiene su botón de cerrar, quiero desde la ventana que la invocó cerrar la ventana invocada por medio de

```
$(document).find("#contenedorventana #boton").click();
```

me funcionaba bien, pero dejó de funcionar el evento click, alguna forma de hacer que mi invocación al evento click funcione?

Nota: Si cierro la ventana desde el botón de cerrar funciona correctamente, el problema es al invocar el evento para cerrarla automáticamente desde la ventana invocadora

Comment: agrega mas informacion sobre tu pregunta, como tu codigo. html, js, etc

Comment: Porque usas un selector que contiene 2 `id`? usar sólo `#boton` debería ser lo mismo, a menos que tengas más de un elemento con el mismo id, lo que sería un problema..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puess investigando he encontrado la solución, aunque aún no he entendido bien por qué funciona así jaja pero bueno, resulta que en vez de

```
$(document).find("#contenedor #botón").click();
```

sólo debía agregar

```
$(document).find("#contenedor #botón")[0].click();
```

Así que pues gracias de todos modos por sus respuestas

> **Fuente:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892113/click-working-with-document-getelementbyid-but-not-with-jquery-selector

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por qué le dices al DOM que busque el elemento si está referenciado por un ID, tampoco debes hacer una búsqueda redundate si ya conoces el botón. Basta con

```
$("#boton").click();
```

O si dices que es un botón dentro de un DIV puedes hacer

```
$("#contenedorventana button").click();
```

Cuidado con este último por que si tienes más de un botón en el DIV actuará de una forma rara.

Comment: Puess ya probé la forma $("#boton").click(); y no me funciona :( lo más extraño es que antes si funcionaba con la opción que describí arriba, el asunto es que puede haber varios divs con ese mismo botón y ID (ya que son ventanas dinámicas y cada ventana tiene su botón de cerrado), al cerrarlas manualmente (dar click en el botón) funciona sin problema, el detalle es cuando quiero invocar ese evento sin darle click al botón, para que lo cierre automáticamente

Answer (score -1):

puedes utilizar javascript puro, aveces no funcionan los metodos de jquery por x o por y. Es por eso que esta librería esta en des uso.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='elemento_1'>click aqui div 1</div>
<div id='elemento_2'>click aqui div 2</div>
<div id='elemento_3'>click aqui div 3</div>
<div id='elemento_4'>click aqui div 4</div>
<script>



$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#elemento_1').on('click', function(){
    alert('click en el boton div 1');
  });
  
  $('#elemento_2').on('click', function(){
    alert('click en el boton div 2');
  });
  
  $('#elemento_3').on('click', function(){
    alert('click en el boton div 3');
  });
  
  $('#elemento_4').on('click', function(){
    alert('click en el boton div 4');
  });
  
});


/* lo pongo dentro de un setTimeout porque el 
elemento debe de existir al momento de ejecutarse
 la instruccion.
*/
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('elemento_1').click();
  document.getElementById('elemento_2').click();
  $('#elemento_3').click();
  $('#elemento_4').click();
}, 600);
</script>
```